# Helper for PagedList supporting unobtrusive Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I'm currently using PagedList (https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/) to manage my paging in an ASP.NET MVC application.

As of today I have started converting some parts of the application to use AJAX, which ASP.NET MVC makes quite easy.

The first problem I have run into however is that the PagedList.MVC helper @Html.PagedListPager is not in any way compatable with unobtrusive AJAX.

All I really need to do is add some attributes to the paging links (see below) and the rest would be taken care of automatically. PagedListPager does not provide any way to do this however.

```
data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#SearchResults"
```

Has anyone run into this and found an elegant solution?

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/creating_a_custom_ajax_helper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added support for unobtrusive AJAX:

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/issues/26#issuecomment-6471793

Comment: I ended up creating my own implementation, I think yours needs some serious work.

Comment: Lot's of 404s there Troy!

Comment: The links all 404. I manually found the view/controller code for anyone who needs them:
https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc4.Example/Controllers/UnobtrusiveAjaxController.cs
https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc4.Example/Views/UnobtrusiveAjax/Index.cshtml
https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc4.Example/Views/UnobtrusiveAjax/UnobtrusiveAjax_Partial.cshtml

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may be the most elegant solution.

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Articles, page => Url.Action("Index", new { s = Model.SearchString, page = page }))

<script>


    var pages = $('#pages a[href^="/"]');

    pages.attr('data-ajax', 'true')
        .attr('data-ajax-mode', 'replace')
        .attr('data-ajax-update', '#SearchResults')
        .attr('data-ajax-method', 'post');


</script>
```

Quick jQuery hack to add the necessary attributes to all links in order for them to be picked up by the unobtrusive ajax module.

The [href^="/"] part ensures that only the clickble links will be modified. If you don't use this, the greyed out Previous link will be clickable.

Comment: I've added non-hacky support: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/issues/26#issuecomment-6471793